# [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource testngtasks

Tags: xml, ant, testng, build.xml

Selenium Webdriver+testNG+ANT
I have an error running -ant runtest
C:\seleniumtests>ant runtest
Buildfile: C:\seleniumtests\build.xml

compileTests:
      [jar] Building jar: C:\seleniumtests\AntruTests.jar

runtest:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource testngtasks. It could not b
e found.

BUILD FAILED
C:\seleniumtests\build.xml:38: Problem: failed to create task or type testng
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

Total time: 1 second

build.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<project name="AntruTests">
    <!-- Properties storage -->
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <!-- Project's folders locations -->

    <property name="project.path" value="." />

    <!-- Set class path libraries to be used for compilation -->
    <path id="class.path">
    <pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-java-2.37.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar"/>
    </path>


     <!-- Title for ReportNG -->
    <property name="report.title" value="Automated tests report for AntruTests"/>

    <!-- Compile classes -->
    <target name="compileTests"> 
        <javac classpathref="class.path"  includeantruntime="false" destdir="C:\seleniumtests" encoding="UTF-8" optimize="off" 
            debug="on" failonerror="true" srcdir="C:\seleniumtests" />

            <jar destfile="AntruTests.jar" basedir="C:\seleniumtests" />
        </target>

    <target name="prepareForRunning" depends="compileTests">

        <delete dir="${tests.results.folder}" />
        <mkdir dir="${tests.results.folder}" />
</target>


    <target name="runtest" depends="compileTests" description="Runtests">
        <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${lib.dir}/testng-6.8.7.jar"/>
<testng outputdir="${testng.output.dir}" classpathref="classes">  
<xmlfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="testng.xml"/>  
             </testng>

</target>
</project>
```

What I am doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [testNG taskdef definition in Ant using Maven dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263301/testng-taskdef-definition-in-ant-using-maven-dependencies)

Comment: Possible a dublicate, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/10896353/3012546
doesnt help, the same error(

Comment: Error message indicates that the task jar for testng cannot be found. Check both the taskdef AND location of the jar. Good way to check is to run ANT in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${lib.dir}/testng-6.8.7.jar"/>
```

Ant processes [taskdef] before setting ${lib.dir}. You need to set absolute path like,

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="/usr/local/lib/testng-6.8.7.jar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${test.classpath}"/>
```

Thanks for help!